# IE 11 Responds with "405 Not Allowed" to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have the following AJAX request that is running successfully for all browsers on our site but returning a 405 for IE 11. I noticed here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2 that IE 11 has some issues with XMLHttpRequest but I wasn't completely clear on what that means. We are returning JSON in the response with the content type set to `application/json`. Additionally, we do use CORS for this request, but everything is working on other browsers.

I apologize with not sharing more information, but I am just wondering if this is a known IE 11 issue that I just can't seem to find online.

```
try {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', this.host, true);
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
        request.send(outboundStr);
        request.onload = function (e) {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    try {
                        const responseObj = JSON.parse(request.response);
                        setSbmId(user, responseObj);
                        user.country = responseObj.c;
                    } catch (ex){
                        util.throw(`FluentD parse error: ${request.response}`, ex);
                    }
                } else {
                    util.throw('FluentD response error')
                }
            }
        };
    } catch (e) {
        util.throw('Failed to send payload to fluentd', e);
    }
```

Comment: the caniuse page clearly states with IE11 `Partial support refers to not supporting json as responseType` - which is probably **not** an issue, as you are parsing the response yourself

Comment: as a test, try removing `request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');` - and, by the way, you don't need to test `request.readyState === 4`  in an onload handler (onload handlers get called **once** when readyState === 4, and not before

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, that is what I assumed, but just wanted to double check.

Comment: can you check the developer tools network tab, does your request send an OPTIONS preflight? does your server respond to such a request?